# Is there a word for "not thinking clearly because of anger"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: two are arguing and one makes a personal attack. They both become angry causing neither to speak reasonably.

Any word for this?

---

EDIT: In my example, instead of 'angry', I should have used the word 'indignant'. I wasn't looking for extremes, like 'seeing red' or 'blinded by rage'.

I also find 'enraged', 'infuriated', and 'apoplectic' not suitable. I'm looking for "a state of irrationality, caused by indignation."

From the responses so far, I think the best expression is "Their judgment became clouded by indignation."

Comment: Well, "clouded judgment" might be used, though it does not identify a cause for the state.

Comment: These have both been mentioned in answers, but I wanted mention that "mad" [actually means](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mad) "Insane", but we use it to mean "angry". Berserk is great option, and is a [reference](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=berserk) to a crazed norse warrior.

Comment: A similar term is "the red mist has descended". This is usually more in reference to competitive events. Eg, in F1 if someone does a rather harsh overtake (not mentioning Maldonado, of course!), then sometimes "the red mist descends" and the person who was overtaken may become really aggressive and try sometime reckless. (I realise that isn't exactly the same as what you have asked, but related :).)

Answer (score 6):

The were *enraged* and *apoplectic* and no doubt synonyms of those, leading them to say things "in a rage" or if really extreme while "seeing the red mist".

Comment: *apoplectic* really has a visual impact for me - good word!

Comment: @KristinaLopez I like how it pops when said, almost as if the speaker were themselves apoplectic and had to spit it out.

Comment: "Seeing red" is a common expression in the US.  I'm not sure most in the US would know what "seeing the red mist" means (nor do I, entirely).

Comment: @HotLicks would you have to know the expression to understand "his bringing the matter up again made me see a red mist and I screamed at him and almost swung my fist".

Comment: @JonHanna - I think the phrase would cause a moment of confusion in the listener.  Whether they would eventually equate it with "seeing red" or simply ignore it as an odd Britishism is hard to predict.

Comment: The image of paralysis in the origin of apoplectic would set it at the opposite end of the *confusion* spectrum from anger. The historic development toward anger would be an interesting exploration.

Comment: I've always understood the term "red mist" to mean "blood". So "seeing the red mist" would mean "seeing blood", either literally (the blood rushes to your head from anger, causing bloodshot eyes) or metaphorically (you're so angry, you fantasize about causing someone to bleed). I'm confused, then, about the phrase "the red mist descends/comes down"... If anything, it's *ascending*, right? Lol

Answer (score 6):

How about [berserk](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/berserk):

> Out of control with anger or excitement; wild or frenzied

Answer (score 5):

The expression *blinded by rage* may suggest the idea of being unable to think and behave reasonably because of anger. Also *mad with rage*.

Comment: It's what I'd use, but OP apparently requires a single word.

Comment: "Blind rage" comes close.

Answer (score 4):

*Enraged, blinded by rage, furious* all suggest losing clarity of mind. The British also use a colloquial *fuming* as adjective to describe that same state of mind.

Answer (score 3):

Normally sane people might do something unwise [*in the heat of the moment*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+heat+of+the+moment):

> if you say or do something in the heat of the moment, you say or do it without thinking because you are angry or excited *Frank doesn't hate you. He just said that in the heat of the moment.*

Answer (score 3):

1. I also prefer **apoplectic**, but to me that connotes being overwhelmed to the point of *physical* impairment.  (e.g. *sputtering with indignation*, or *incoherent with rage*).

   //In my mind, apoplectic rage conjures the image of someone SO overcome with anger, they can't even articulate their emotional state or arguments--  that they're red-faced and shouting or sputtering, with blood-pressure spiking, looking like they're about to burst a blood vessel and give themselves a stroke.

   [This](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/apoplectic) entry sums it up quite neatly:

   > Someone who is apoplectic is not just mad — they're so filled with rage, they can barely communicate. If your mother is apoplectic, you better hope it isn't over something you did.
   >   Apoplectic comes from a Greek word that means to "disable by a stroke." What is a stroke? The sudden loss of consciousness or control caused when a blood vessel in the brain ruptures or becomes blocked. When this happens, a person becomes apoplectic. This word also applies to someone who acts so upset, it is like he or she is having a stroke.
2. However, seems like you're looking for something that suggests distinctly (solely?) an impact on the mental/emotional state?  For which, I'd suggest **paroxsym**, or perhaps **paroxysm of rage**?

   The two key words in the [definitions](http://www.memidex.com/paroxysm) seem to be: *sudden* and *uncontrollable* bursts of emotion.  And if somebody's having such outbursts, it's probably fair to say they're irrational and not thinking clearly.

   Potential synonyms: **conniption**; **furor** (though this could also imply group anger); **in the throes of** anger (or of passion? as in, distinct from reason, not as a euphemism for passionate love. //either way, throes connotes some degree of struggle or suffering: unpleasant, painful, or unwanted emotional state);
3. Emphasis on internal state, less so action/behavior-oriented: **incensed**  (connotations: you're so angry, it's as if you're on fire--  similarly: **makes my blood boil**); **exasperated** (which may or may not be able to convey the intensity of emotion?); to **seethe** or be in a **ferment**; **fuming** (e.g. *fuming mad*); **wrought** or **overwrought** with anger; **maddened** or **besieged** by anger (to wit: rational faculties besieged by angry thoughts, OR the very thoughts themselves besieged by anger); hostage to/paralyzed by a **tempest** of rage/emotion;

Comment: Hello 3jane. Did you see OP's edit? EDIT: In my example, instead of 'angry', I should have used the word 'indignant'. I wasn't looking for extremes, like 'seeing red' or 'blinded by rage'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Good point-- perhaps **piqued** would be a better fit? (or: *a fit of pique*, *a state of pique*). Carries the sense of a particularly vexing or personal injury, like 'getting under someone's skin.'

OP's example in mind, I especially like the play on meanings, considering: 1) 'a pique' could also refer to a provocation (e.g. personal attack), or the argument itself. 2) etymology goes: a sharp point --> to prick, or sting 
//for me, this conjures the idea of verbal sparring/jousting, trying to argue/defend your *point*, a repartee landing too *sharply*, etc. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *[go off the deep end](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/go-off-or-go-in-off-the-deep-end)* is often used in such circumstances

> Give way immediately to an emotional outburst, especially of anger.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 1):

***The red mist came down***; is popular nowadays, often to describe footballers who have a moment of rage. Some careers are ruined by a predisposition to this.

Answer (score 1):

***[Unhinged](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unhinged)*** OED or by approximate association ***[Unglued](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unglued)***

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Mentally unbalanced; deranged:

Etymology

> ***Unhinged***: "*thrown into confusion*," 1719, past participle adjective from *unhinge*.
>
> ***Unhinge***: recorded earlier in the mental sense of "*to disorder*" the mind, etc. (1612) than in the literal one of "*to take* (a door, etc.)
>   *off its hinges*" (1616); from *un*- (2) "*opposite of*" + *hinge* (n.).
>
> ***Hinge*** as a verb meaning "*to attach by a hinge*" is recorded only from 1758.

Literally:

> *My husband was so furious the door came **unhinged** when he slammed it*

Metaphorically:

> *My husband is **unhinged**!*

[Synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/confuse) of confuse(d).

Applying it to the OP:

The two people arguing began **connected** to each other at some level. A healthy argument pursues a deeper level of intellectual or emotional unity on the dividing issue, but the *ad hominem* attack *tears the door from its hinges*, or *unglues the coupled pair*. From that point forward, their angry comments aggravate disunity rather than promoting unity. Furthermore, that breech in the friendship tears each individual apart inside. As they unhinge internally, their argument unhinges externally.

Somebody needs to stop the argument and put the doors back on their hinges!

Answer (score 0):

Most people become emotionally unstable and are temporarily unable to reason when they get very angry. In such cases, most of the answers already given will fit (enraged, blinded by rage, apoplectic, and all synonyms). But if you are looking for a single word meaning "impaired reasoning caused by rage", I'm afraid there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

You could say they were *maddened*.  This has the convenient double meaning of "made angry" and "made insane".

Another possibility is *infuriated*.

Answer (score 0):

For more alternatives, in addition to those already supplied, you have:

- ***gone ape***, ***gone apeshit***, ***gone bananas*** — This doesn't necessarily imply anger, as one can "go ape" with delight as well.  But it does imply a degree of irrational behaviour.
- ***seeing red*** — Unlike the "red mist" described in another answer, this has currency outwith sportspersons.  ☺  This is specifically anger, although it implies impaired perception and not necessarily impaired judgment or reasoning.  Eric Partridge's dictionary of slang doesn't have this.  Others do, however, usually listing it as a colloquialism.

Interesting aside: There have been various studies that show that a predisposition to anger correlates with an increased disposition to see red; and that colour perception is influenced by level of anger.  The psychologists are busy proving the dictionaries right all along.  Except for M. Partridge's, that is.  ☺

#### Further reading

- Andrew J. Elliot, Markus A. Maier, et al.: "Color-in-Context Theory". *Advances in Experimental Social Psychology*.  Elsevier. 2012.  pp. 61–125.
- Adam K. Fetterman, Michael D. Robinson, Robert D. Gordon, and Andrew J. Elliot.  "Anger as Seeing Red: Perceptual Sources of Evidence".  *Social Psychological and Personality Science*  **2(3)**. May 2011. pp. 311–316.
  doi: [10.1177/1948550610390051](http://dx.doi.org/10.1177%2F1948550610390051). PMC3399410.

Answer (score 0):

Tunnel-vision may be suitable.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved by providing an explanation of *why* you believe it may be suitable, including appropriate references and links, as StackExchange has higher expectations of posts than a typical discussion forum would. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Berserker rage comes to mind, a person biting their lip/tongue, and this throws them into a blind monstrous rage with no thought of the harm to others, they kill for joy of it. Not that I know of such things I'm just a newbie writer so, forgive me If i's freaking anyone one out.